# Winmail.dat and PHP script decoding

Tags: php, attachment, email-attachments, winmail.dat

I am working on a php script that corrects file attachments. One of the cases I need to handle is winmail.dat type.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16792842/how-to-extract-tnef-winmail-dat-using-a-php-script/16812686#16812686) solution, however I have no access to shell and the php environment I am working with is restricted and does not allow shell_exec.

Is there any other way of converting this type of file to a readable text file using php only?

Comment: if `shell_exec` disabled form `php.ini` you cannot use this function on the server. you have to contact your host to enable it

Comment: Unfortunately, this option is out of the question due to the nature of the environment.

Comment: You might be able to use a web service in your environment, like http://tud.at/php/tnef/index.php